# Wbadmin [startbackup] keeps prompting for password

Tags: password, scheduled-task, batch-file, unc, wbadmin

I am running Wbadmin for backup purposes in a batch file, however the batch execution halts, prompting for a password although the password is provided.

First attempt - include password in command:

```
cmd /c "C:\Windows\system32\wbadmin.exe" start backup -backuptarget:\\acrux\BACKUP02 -include:"c:" -quiet -allcritical -noVerify -user:backupuser password:operbackup
```

Second attempt - Echo password (with pipe):

```
cmd /c echo operbackup | "C:\Windows\system32\wbadmin.exe" start backup -backuptarget:\\acrux\BACKUP02 -include:"c:" -quiet -allcritical -noVerify -user:backupuser
```

The batch file is being fired from Task Scheduler  running with maximum privileges within an Administrator-level account. Platform: Windows 7 & 8

Comment: `-include:"c:"` option gives me `The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect` error. Should be `-include:c:` without double quotes (win8).

Comment: Correct, however with the right syntax it will keep prompting for the password:  "C:\Windows\system32\wbadmin.exe" start backup -backuptarget:\\acrux\BACKUP02 -include:c: -quiet -allcritical -noVerify -user:backupuser

Comment: Should be `-password:operbackup` instead of `password:operbackup` (missing leading dash in parameter name).

Comment: you also don't need to use `-include:c:` when using `-allcritical` as `-allcritical` will include the c: anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to passing parameters to a batch file with a maximum of 9! The tenth parameter (password) was ignored, forcing the prompt!!!